# create a right aligned multi line text field in swt

Tags: java, layout, swt

Is there any way to create a right aligned multi lined text field in SWT without applying SWT.WRAP style? I need to have the horizontal scroll bar in the text field which disappears when WRAP is used.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `SWT.MULTI | SWT.RIGHT` as the style for the `Text`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.RIGHT);
    text.setText("First line\nsecond line");

    shell.open();
    shell.pack();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work on macOS. The source of `Text` appears to support it but it just gives left alignment. Using `SWT.SINGLE` instead of `SWT.MULTI` does work! Using SWT.WRAP also works.

Comment: @greg-449 Huh, interesting. Wonder if a `StyledText` would help.

Comment: i have tried the same in Styled text also. But no luck. I wonder if it depends on the parent composite. Because it seems to work fine in the above example when no composite is used.

Comment: @SunnyV Still works fine if I add the `Text` to a `Composite`. Are you testing it on macOS? Adding an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question would help.

Comment: @Baz I have tried the example code you have provided. If you try to edit the text further you could see that the text is auto wrapping and hence the horizontal scroll bar is not activated(I have added the styles SWT.H_SCROLL, SWT.V_SCROLL).

Comment: @SunnyV Ah, yes. It appears it doesn't handle wrapping well. I'm afraid I don't know of a solution then.